# Remove trailing slash if index.php is being used

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on a new service which is powered by a backend API, the location of the API is as follows...

> api.nblackburn.me/jobtrackr/

but how instead of having this...

> api.nblackburn.me/jobtrackr/?action=signin

could i change it to this...

> api.nblackburn.me/jobtrackr?action=signin

without it being added again. I have seen this being done on several websites and was wondering how its done as the trailing slash is very unpleasant to look at there. I know its only a cosmetic change but any help would be great, thanks again.

Even stack overflow is using this method, for example...

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/955822/**nblackburn?tab=reputation**

Kind Regards,
**Nathaniel Blackburn**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rewrite Rule (.*?)/\?(.*) $1?$2 [NC,P,L]
```

Does something like this work?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, ill check this out shortly, it means a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i removed the directory and called it jobtracker.php and used this to remove the extention `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`